# What is the difference between functions from keras.backend and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to customize the loss function of keras. I saw the example:

import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

```
def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)
```

Can I use something like:

```
def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.mean(y_pred)
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Both are same and computes the mean of elements across dimensions of a tensor and Equivalent to Numpy mean i.e np.mean. Also it is tf.math.reduce_mean.